# Difference between when select x from $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in discrete logarithm Problem?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, number-theory

Reading "Security Arguments for Digital Signatures and Blind Signatures" paper, I confused by some questions.

- Q1. when it refers to "El Gamal signature scheme",

  The key generation algorithm: it chooses a random large prime $p$, of length $n$ polynomial in $k$, and a generator $g$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$, both public. Then, for a random
  secret key $x \in \mathbb{Z}/(p − 1)\mathbb{Z}$, it computes the public key $y = gx \mod p$

  why $x$ select from group $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$,but not $\mathbb{Z}_p$? what is the difference?

Comment: please check the update of your question with latex.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ denotes a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) that is just integers mod the prime $p$, i.e., $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$. This field (by definition of a field) has two operations: addition and multiplication, where the multiplication group (denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$) is defined only on the non-zero elements $\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$. Then, since $g$ is a generator of the multiplicative group of size $p-1$, the exponent $x$ should be sampled from $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}=\{0,1,\ldots,p-2\}$ (which by the way is not a finite field).

Answer (score 1):

Because $\mathbb{Z}/{p\mathbb{Z}}$ when used for El-Gamal is used in its multiplicative form: we have a generator $g$ such that all powers of $g$ cycle through $\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ (so $0$ is excluded) and as $g^{p-1} =1 \pmod{p}$ by Fermat's little theorem, the powers $x$ we use for the generator and which we use as the private key in the DL scheme essentially takes values in $\{0,\ldots,p-2\}$ (as $x=0$ and $x=p-1$ both yield $g^x=1$), i.e. $g^x = g^{x'} \pmod{p}$ iff $x = x'\pmod{p-1}$. Hence the fact we have $p-1$ choices for $x$.